# Console application starting another process environment variables not accessible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb6, console-application

I have a VB6 executable which is accessing some system environment variables. I have implemented a .NET console application which checks if those environment variables exist, creates them if needed, and then runs the VB6 application by calling `Process.Start`.

Doing this, the VB6 application cannot find the environment variables and it says they don't exist.

If I run the VB6 application from Windows Explorer it works fine and can find the variables.

So it seems the VB6 app is running under the context of .NET console app and cannot access the system environment variables!

**Code to set the environment vars .NET Cosnole app:**

```
foreach(var varObject in Variables)
{
    var envVar = Envrionment.GetEnvironmentVariable(varObject.Name , 
                      EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(envVar)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(varObject.Name,varObject.Value,
             EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    }
}
```

**Code to run the VB6 app from .NET Cosnole app:**

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(VB6ApplicationFilePath);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true
processInfo.WindwoStyle= ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: I re-tagged assuming you meant [tag:vb.net] instead of [tag:vba] and [tag:.net].

Comment: can you please share the problematic section of your code?  (First, see: **"[mcve]"**)

Comment: And how to you set the environment variables?

Comment: You seem to be missing the actual setting of the environment variables when you posted the update, can you add the missing bits?

Comment: Just updated. Thank you.

Comment: I think by setting it to Machine target you are in fact making it available to all new processes started from Windows Explorer, but *not your program*. Try simply removing this parameter. Or, you will have to set it for your current process as well. Environment variables are inherited from the process that spawned the new process, not from the machine, so whatever you spawn from your own program inherits the environment variables of your own program. Since you're modifying the machine variable, and not your own, you need to spawn the program from explorer, or modify your own variables.

Comment: Unless you actually need to make them permanent I would in fact not do that. Simply remove the last parameter and set it for your own process. When you then use `Process.Start` to spawn your VB.NET program, it will inherit the variables, but they will not be permanent. This allows your program to use different variable values each time, since with your solution, next time the variables will be set and thus won't be overridden.

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, I do need to run the VB6 app outside the scope of .NET console app. I don't want these two to be tied together. My VB6 application which I don't have its code. Is trying to read these system environment variables. That's why I am having a .NET app to make sure the system env variables are created before I run the VB app. How can I spawn the program from Explorer or somehow it is not under the .NET app?

Answer (score 2):

A copy of a program's environment is passed to a program that it starts. As it is a copy the second program only sees the state it was in when given it (and changes it made). No other program can change another program's environment.

When using `ShellExecute` (which you tell `ProcessStart` to) you are asking Explorer to start the program for you. The program will get a copy of Explorer's environment.

When changing the system environment, programs can send a message to all windows open saying environment has changed (as `setx` does - see `setx /?`). But ONLY Explorer.exe pays attention to this message. So only programs started by explorer after explorer receives this message will see the changes.

These are the API calls that .NET calls. In Windows all programs are started by `CreateProcessEx` (or older programs `CreateProcess`). `Shellexecute` and `ShellexecuteEx` process the command like you typed it in Explorer's Start - Run dialog (Winkey + R) then changes it and calls `CreateProcessEx`.

At the command prompt. Type

```
set MyCat=PewResearch
cmd /k echo %MyCat%
```

We set an environment variable, start a new command prompt that prints that variable.

This is the message that notifies

> **WM_SETTINGCHANGE**
>
> The system sends the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to all
> top-level windows when the SystemParametersInfo function changes a
> system-wide setting or when policy settings have changed.
>
> Applications should send WM_SETTINGCHANGE to all top-level windows
> when they make changes to system parameters. (This message cannot be
> sent directly to a window.) To send the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to
> all top-level windows, use the SendMessageTimeout function with the
> hwnd parameter set to HWND_BROADCAST.

Comment: When I set UseShellExecute = true. Still, the VB6 application cannot file the environment variable. How can I run the VB6 app somehow it is not bound to the .NET process? What is the right approach? Many thanks

Comment: Don't use `UseShellExecute`. My answer is about why not to.

Comment: Also see `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` .

Comment: whether I use it or not, the VB6 application cannot find the machine environment variables when executed by the process!

Comment: Are you changing them in a way that causes a broadcast message about the changes. Plus programmers should never change system level settings.

Comment: "When using ShellExecute (which you tell ProcessStart to) you are asking Explorer to start the program for you." 

That's not actually true, despite the name. 

Your general point (apps get the environment from their creator on startup and only Explorer updates its environment block when WM_SETTINGCHANGED fires) is correct. See https://jira.reactos.org/browse/CORE-14397 for details on how that happens.