# How to update Windows environment variables after Ansible's win_environment module?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ansible, windows-server-2012

I am using Ansible to configure our Windows Servers 2012.

I am using Ansible's Windows modules: `win_xxx`. All modules are working fine except for

- `win_environment`
- `win_path`

I think the `win_path` depends `win_environment` module in my case.

I am installing

- `JDK`
- `Apache Ant`
- `Apache Tomcat8`.

Installation works fine and setting up the environment variables for

- `JAVA_HOME`
- `ANT_HOME`

is not working as expected. The server is not updated with the new environment variables. I need to sign out and sign in back to the server in order the new variables are updated. Is there any way to update the system in Ansible or in Windows Batch/Powershell without signing in and out?

Comment: `setx` command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262835/console-application-starting-another-process-environment-variables-not-accessibl/51264491#51264491 for why. Note to do current process AND future processes started by explorer you use `set` and `setx`. You can't change current programs.

Answer (score -1):

just to remind that "User level environment" variables will be set, but not available until the user has logged off and on again. 
check then either you have selected "user" as level on you win_environment module.