# Code cannot retrieve the value of an environmental variable I just created in Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, environment-variables

I just created a Windows environment variable like this:

[image]

However, when I try to retrieve its value in code that I'm debugging, it's null:

[image]

Why isn't this working?

---

My question is related [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262835/console-application-starting-another-process-environment-variables-not-accessibl), as pointed out in the comments here.

I've reviewed that question and I agree that the root cause of the behavior I've observed and that which is at the heart of the referenced question is the same: that any process started in Windows inherits the environment of the process that started it.  However, to say that my question is a duplicate is wrong, in my opinion.

Behaviors can be explained by the same root cause, but that doesn't mean they're duplicates; distinct questions are allowed to have *some* overlap.  I know the commenter was able to locate the related question, but I ask myself: would *most* people be able to search and locate that page starting from the vantage point I had, without some prior knowledge of how these things worked?  I *assumed* Visual Studio was unique in that it loaded environmental variables for use with the .NET runtimes of debugged applications.  The referenced question is not about Visual Studio at all; it's about a VB6 process that starts another process.  Again, the root causes are the same, but I had a gap in knowledge -- as might most other people who assume what I did while developing in Visual Studio -- which prevented me from searching for and identifying the referenced question as an answer to my *unique* circumstance.

I think it would be totally appropriate to have a separate answer *to my question* which directs readers to the referenced question or one of its answers and excerpts the important details.  That way, these two sibling questions can be linked for future reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console application starting another process environment variables not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262835/console-application-starting-another-process-environment-variables-not-accessibl)

Comment: @AdrianHHH  -- please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio seems to load all environmental variables when it starts.  Close Visual Studio and re-open it.  Here's what the same code does after this:

[image]

Comment: Any process loads the environment variables when it starts. In this case it is not Visual Studio but the application that is started by Visual Studio.